# How to display List.generate horizontally in flutter

Tags: flutter

```
Wrap(
        children: List.generate(channelIds.length,
            (index) => chipItem(channelIds[index], AppUtils.filteredByChannelId)),
      ),
```

So I have used List.generate but I want to display items in horizontally. I applied,

```
direction: Axis.horizontal,
```

In a Wrap, I gave a direction but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
return SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      child: Wrap(
        direction: Axis.horizontal,
        children: List.generate(
            channelIds.length,
            (index) =>
                chipItem(channelIds[index], AppUtils.filteredByChannelId)),
      ),
    );
```

above code works for me

Answer (score -1):

instead of using List.generate use this

```
  Wrap(
  children: [
    for(var item in channelIds)
      your widget here
  ],
),
```

Comment: But it is not displaying horizontally

Comment: pls add some image for us to see

Answer (score -1):

use like this

```
 return Wrap(
    children: ['1']
        .asMap()
        .map((i, element) => MapEntry(i, Text(i.toString())))
        .values
        .toList(),
 );
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).